# Connecting to vpn from behind a router (with dynamic IP)

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding

I've made a pptp server on Ubuntu and considering I'm fairly new at this stuff I somehow made it work (tested from a friend behind a router without any port forwarding). Granted it was kinda slow, but it still established a connection (connecting from Win 7).

Now the idea is that I want to connect to my home network from Germany (for example to be able to see the other HALF of youtube, which is blocked here for some unknown reason). But when I got here it turned out I can't connect (error 619). After I've read a bit about it I'm guessing my ISP is blocking the ports needed by the pptp and I really don't know what to do. I'd appreciate any ideas on how to set up my server so I can connect to it.

P. S. At least ssh and xrdp are working fine so I still have some way to connect to my PC at home... :) Also I'm a real newbie at this stuff so more details are welcome :)

Comment: Not sure what exactly you would like to accomplish, but if it's only for web traffic you could setup a web proxy.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best way to fix this is to change the port on the VPN server to something which your ISP will allow, something like 80/443/22/25.

That you can check by running a netcat server and try to connect to that port from germany.

Run this command on VPN server. This will open a port given in command

```
 # nc -v -l -k -p <port>
```

Then try to connect to your server by telnet.

```
 # telnet <VPN_SERVER> <port>
```

Once you find a port which your ISP allows, simply run your openvpn server on that port and change the server port in the client and it will work like charm.